# Is there a CRC or criptographic function for generating smaller size unique results from unique inputs?

Tags: cryptography

I have a manufacturer unique number ID of 128 bits that I cannot change and it's size is just too long for our purpose (2^128). This is on some embedded micro controller.

One idea is to compute a (run time) CRC32 or hash for narrowing the results but I am not sure for unicity CRC32 as a example: this can be unique for 2^32

Or what king of cryptography function I can use for guarantee unicity of 32 bits output based on unique input?

Thanks for clarifications,

Comment: You can use any cryptographic hash and truncate the output to the length you need. But is is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Truncated digests come to mind as suggested by Zaph. But be careful because there's no reduction in proof the truncated hash has the same properties as the complete hash. At minimum, your function should digest the output buffer size in bits. Just send it into the hash like with the 128-bit UID. Also see Kelsey's work on [truncated hashes](https://www.google.com/search?q=kelsey+truncated+hash).

Comment: You can't uniquely map 2^128 -> 2^32 ([Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).  You could store the 128 bit number as either 2 64-bit values or 4 32-bit values, depending on what your actual constraints are.  Dragging around an extra 12 bytes is annoying, but probably less than strings you may be doing instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all these ID values in advance, then you can check them using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). You can save space by storing only as many bits of each hash value as are necessary to tell them apart if them happen to land in the same bucket.

If not, then you're going to have a hard time, I'm afraid.

Let's assume these 128-bit IDs are produced as the output of a cryptographic hash function (e.g., [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)), so each ID resembles 128 bits chosen uniformly at random.

If you reduce these to 32-bit values, then the best you can hope to achieve is a set of 32-bit numbers where each bit is 0 or 1 with uniform probability. You could do this by calculating the CRC32 checksum, or by simply discarding 96 bits — it makes no difference.

32 bits is not enough enough to avoid collisions. The collision probability exceeds 1 in a million after just 93 inputs, and 1 in a thousand after 2,900 inputs. After 77,000 inputs, the collision probability reaches 50%. ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack)).

So instead, your only real options are to somehow reverse-engineer the ID values into something smaller, or implement some external means of replacing these IDs with sequential integers (e.g., using a hash table).